# Install pymatbridge on Windows

Tags: python, matlab, zeromq, ipython-magic

I am trying to use pymatbridge. I am using python 2.7.9 64 bits on Windows and Canopy 1.5.5 and when I put the following code in ipython notebook

```
from pymatbridge import Matlab
mlab = Matlab(executable='matlab')
mlab.start()
```

I receive this error:

> ---
>
> ZMQError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>
> 1 from pymatbridge import Matlab
>
> 2 mlab = Matlab(executable='matlab')
>
> ----> 3 mlab.start()
>
> C:\Users\Administrateur\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pymatbridge\pymatbridge.pyc in start(self)
>       205             port = self.socket.bind_to_random_port(self.socket_addr)
>       206             self.socket_addr = self.socket_addr + ":%s"%port
>   --> 207             self.socket.unbind(self.socket_addr)
>       208 
>       209         # Start the MATLAB server in a new process
>
> C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.5.3123.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\socket.pyd in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.unbind (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:5247)()
>
> ZMQError: No such file or directory

I've tried pip install pyzmq.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with `sudo apt-get install python-zmq`?

Comment: I am using windows 7. I've tried pip install pyzmq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `executable` you should not call `matlab` but add the path to the location of your MATLAB executable. In my case (using OSX) it is:
`'/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/matlab'`.

I found this by typing `matlabroot` in the MATLAB Command Window (returns `/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app`) and adding `/bin/matlab`.

In some cases just `mlab = Matlab()` works, see [my earlier error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805780/how-to-call-matlab-executable-for-python-on-cluster/42907129#42907129) running pymatbridge on a cluster and the [pymatbridge github page](https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge).