# How to call MATLAB executable for Python on cluster?

Tags: python, matlab, cluster-computing, zeromq

I am using a [python-matlab-bridge](https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge) that calls MATLAB from python by starting it on a ZMQ socket. On my own computer, I hand the bridge the location of the executable (in this case MATLAB 2014B):

```
executable='/Applications/MATLAB_R2014b.app/bin/matlab'
```

and everything works as required and the printed statement is:

```
Starting MATLAB on ZMQ socket ipc:///tmp/pymatbridge-49ce56ed-f5b4-43c4-8d53-8ae0cd30136d
```

Now I want to do the same on a cluster. Through `module avail` I find there are two MATLAB versions (2015a and 2016b) available and located at the following path:

```
/opt/ud/LOCAL/etc/modulefiles/matlab.
```

When I now call MATLAB using:

```
executable='/opt/ud/LOCAL/etc/modulefiles/matlab/MATLAB_R2015a.app/bin/matlab'
```

the error:

```
 Starting MATLAB on ZMQ socket ipc:///tmp/pymatbridge-95775445-359d-441f-803a-7193eedbf215    
Send 'exit' command to kill the server
............................................................MATLAB session timed out after 60 seconds
```

is returned. It cannot find the MATLAB executable. How to proceed?

Comment: Can you start MATLAB manually with that path? Are those Linux servers in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found a method that works that is very simple. In the .pbs script I load the MATLAB module using

```
module load matlab/2015a
```

Then in the Python script the command

```
mlab = Matlab()
```

automatically detects the correct MATLAB path. I thus do not need to specify the path using the optional `executable` argument.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 0:

Check whether the code-segment responsible for "remote" launch of MATLAB goes well - for details about params, check **`pymatbridge.py`**:

```
    ### class _Session( object ): _____________________________
    ...

    def _run_server(self):
        code = self._preamble_code()
        code.extend([
            "matlabserver('%s')" % self.socket_addr
        ])
        command = '%s %s %s "%s"' % ( self.executable,
                                      self.startup_options,
                                      self._execute_flag(),
                                      ','.join( code )
                                      )
        subprocess.Popen( command,
                          shell  = True,
                          stdin  = subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout = subprocess.PIPE
                          )
```

If such invocation works on any Cluster-Node you will try to harness in a massively distributed MATLAB scenario, the problem goes into ZeroMQ messaging part, if not, the remote server simply cannot launch a **`_Session`**, while the messaging ( and all it's `{ ipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// | vmci:// }` transport-classes available for a massively-distributed computing ) is not to be blamed.

### Step 1:

If Step 0 ( a **`subprocess.Popen(...)`** invocation ) works well on all remote nodes, check all the ZeroMQ / pymatbridge pre-requisites ( dynamic loader settings - lines added to all remote cluster nodes' `.bash_profile` ( or similar file for respective shell ).

Yes, a tedious task to prove all remote nodes on the cluster meet these, but without checking these, there is no warranty a remote node can operate the remote MATLAB process connected via otherwise smart and powerful tool, like the `pymatbridge` is.

Comment: You were right in the fact that the problem was the remote launch of MATLAB.

Comment: Glad you have found my answer to be helpfull.